# How can I add an image to my webpage from my pictures library?

Tags: html, image

Could someone please tell me what I have done wrong with my code:

```
<img id="myimage" onclick="changeImage()"
src="rightarrow.gif" width="40" height="20">
```

On my webpage it does not appear. Is there a special name for the image I need to put in? It is saved as rightarrow and is a gif file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make it any clearer...

Comment: What do you mean by in the same folder as my HTML file?

Comment: Does the folder that contains the HTML file, also contain the image file? Or do you maybe have a folder called "images"?

Comment: I just tried moving it from "My Pictures" into the folder with my html file and it didn't help. I tried that before too..

Comment: Someone is trolling...

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug first before asking question. You can view the page source in browser and click on the src link to check whether the path is reachable or not. It will be more helpful if you can post full html code.

**This is how it looks. You need to click on the link indicated by the arrow:-**

[image]